# Consider the following congruences: $x \equiv 3\pmod 4$ $x \equiv 11\pmod{8}$ $x \equiv 13\pmod{16}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the following congruences:

(1) $x \equiv 3\pmod 4$

(2) $x \equiv 11\pmod{8}$

(3) $x \equiv 13\pmod{16}$

Then

(A).  (1) and (2) have a common solution but (1) and (3) do not have a common solution.

(B).  (1) and (2) have a common solution but (2) and (3) do not have a common solution.

(C).  (1) and (3) have a common solution but (1) and (2) do not have a common solution.

(D).  (1) and (3) have a common solution but (2) and (3) do not have a common solution.

(E).  (2) and (3) have a common solution but (1) and (2) do not have a common solution.

(F).  (2) and (3) have a common solution but (1) and (3) do not have a common solution.

(G).  All the three congruences have a common solution.

(H).  Any two of the congruences have a common solution.

We know that if the integers $m_i$ where $i = 1,2,3,...,n$ are relatively prime in pairs then then congruences $x \equiv a_i\pmod m_i$ where $a_i$ are integers have one and only one common solution congruent $\pmod M$ where $M = m_1m_2...m_n$. But here $m_1 = 4, m_2 = 8, m_3 = 16$ are not relatively primes. So Chinese Remainder theorem is not applicable here. How we can solve the problem ?

Comment: You should be able to determine what $x$ is equivalent to mod $4$ immediately from the second two statements.

Comment: From last two, $x = 11+8m$ and $x = 13+16n$ where $m,n \in \Bbb Z$ gives $11+8m = 13+16n \implies 8(m-2n) = 2 \implies m-2n = \frac{1}{4}$ but $m-2n \in \Bbb Z$ and $\frac{1}{4} \notin \Bbb Z$

Comment: That's a valid approach too

Comment: Immediate consequence of the basic CRT solvability criterion in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\equiv 13\pmod{16}$ then $x=13+16k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ which implies that $$x=13+16k\equiv 5\pmod{8}\qquad, \qquad x=13+16k\equiv 1\pmod{4}.$$ Hence (3) does not have a common solutions with (1) (because and $x \equiv 3\pmod 4$) and (2) (because and $x \equiv 11\equiv 3\pmod 8$).

Does (1) and (2) have a common solutions? If $x\equiv 11\pmod{8}$ then what is $x$ congruent to modulo $4$?

Comment: @Sangam Academy Any further doubt? Have you tried to compare (1) and (2)?

Comment: Yes, from first two, $x = 3+4p = 11+ 8q \implies 4(p-2q) = 8 \implies p-2q = 2$ which is possible for $p = 4$ and $q = 1$. So (1) and (2) have a common solution.

Comment: @Sangam Academy  Yes, we may also say that $3+8k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ are all the common solutions of (1) and (2).

Comment: @Sangam Academy Was my answer of any help or did you find the solution in another way?

Comment: Yes, your answer is helpful. But your comment "$3+8k$ with $k \in \Bbb Z$ are all common solutions of (1) and (2)" is unclear for me.

Comment: Note that $x=3+8k$ are all the solutions of (2). Moreover $x=3+8k\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$  and therefore it solves also (1).

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).